# Proof of center of mass formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

You know the center of mass equation:
X=(x1*m1+x2*m2)/(m1+m2)

Can you please demonstrate a proof of this? Maybe usimg torques?

Comment: That's a [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The center of mass (CoM) is not an equation, it's a definition.

The center of gravity, on the other hand, is an equation.

So yes, that formula is just a definition, but it is not a random one. After you define it, it turns out to have multiple nice properties. But that's not by chance, but because of that special form.

And that's because it is the weighed average position. That means, it is the average position, but weighed according to masses.

If you have two masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$, in positions 1 and 2, such that $m_1$=$m_2$, then you would easily compute average in the same way you calculate your average score in school:

$$\vec{r}_{mean}=\frac{\vec{r}_1+\vec{r}_2}{2}$$

And it is obviously right in the middle of them. Half the distance. Notice that this is the same as

$$\vec{r}_{mean}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\vec{r}_1+\vec{r}_2\right)$$

Now, what if $m_2$ is twice $m_1$? Then $m_2$ is like having two units of $m_1$ placed in the same site. That's like having three particles:

$$\vec{r}_{mean}=\frac{\vec{r}_1+\vec{r}_2+\vec{r}_2}{3}=\frac{\vec{r}_1+2\cdot\vec{r}_2}{3}$$

And that's the same as

$$\vec{r}_{mean}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\vec{r}_1+2\cdot\vec{r}_2\right)=\frac{1}{3} \vec{r}_1+\frac{2}{3}\vec{r}_2$$

Can we generalize this? What if it is $m_2=1.5 m_1$? or any other? Check that $1/3$ and $2/3$ are precisely $m_1/M$ and $m_2/M$, where $M$ is the total mass.

So yes, we have

$$\vec{r}_{CM} = \frac{m_1}{M}\vec{r}_1+\frac{m_2}{M}\vec{r}_2+\dots=\frac{1}{M}\sum_i m_i \vec{r_i}$$

The usual formula. It's a definition, yes, but it is the **average**, and that makes it have special properties that other definitions would not have.

Answer (score 0):

A definition cannot be proved, but it can be motivated.

Suppose that you have masses $m_i$ at locations $\vec{r}_i$. Let us study the total torque given by gravity on these masses:

$$
\vec{T} 
= \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times m_i g (-\hat{z}) 
= - \left( \sum_i \vec{r}_i m_i \right) \times g \hat{z}.
$$

We are looking for a point $\vec{R}$ such that, if $M = \sum_i m_i$ is the total mass, then
$$
\vec{T} = -M \vec{R} \times g \hat{z}.
$$

Thus, we want to have 
$$M \vec{R} \times g \hat{z} = \left( \sum_i \vec{r}_i m_i \right) \times g \hat{z}.$$

It's now obvious that we can take
$$\vec{R} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_i \vec{r}_i m_i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Do note that this equation works only for a 2 particle system. [image]

[image]

If you have more than 2 masses, you have to add the corresponding m*x (m3x3... m4x4 and so on) terms on the left and the respective masses (m3, m4...) in the brackets on the right. You can see how this generalises into the sum notation mentioned by other users.

Comment: The reference point is marked with a x and the pivot with the triangle. You can think of the 2 masses being held together by a massless and rigid rod that sapns from m2 to the reference position. If you pivot the the system at its COM, the contact force should balance the weight of the system without causing any rotation.

Comment: The "pivot" here is imaginary and only applies if the rod is in equilibrium